# Find out the shell which was used to run the process in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, sh, ps

I recently got stuck in a situation where I need to find out the name of the `shell` for a list of process (or for a single process, using `pid`). Is there a way we can find it out (preferably using `ps` and `grep` command).

Comment: Sure. You should see what the PPID of your process in question is, look for that process, take its PPID and continue until you find the shell. `pstree` can help, too

Comment: @GMichael Is there any other solution instead of having code based recursive calls. I mean is there a command that you can provide me because there are other processing needs to be done, so I just wanted it to be as concise as possible

Comment: Not clear what you're asking - is your process one that you know has been started from a shell (i.e. a child process of a shell)?  Or do you have a running script, and you want to know which interpreter is running?

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes I have a list of process that I know has been started from a shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know that the processes have been started from a shell, you just have to find the command name of the parent process, whose process id can be obtained using `ps`, e. g. with the OUTPUT FORMAT CONTROL option `oppid`.

```
for pid in ${list[*]}; do echo -n $pid:; ps p`ps p$pid hoppid` hocomm; done
```

Details

```
for pid in ${list[*]}; do …; done
```

The commands `…` are executed once for each element in `list` with the variable `pid` set to each element (process ID) in turn. See [Looping Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs).

The construct `${list[*]}` expands to all elements in `list`; in `bash` this works if `list` is an array variable (set by e. g. `list=(1234 5678)`) **as well as** if `list` is a simple variable with white-space-separated elements (set by e. g. `list="1234 5678"`). See [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and [Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays).

```
echo -n $pid:
```

outputs e. g. `1234:` without a newline, so that following output appears directly behind the `:`. See [Bash Builtin Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins).

```
ps p$pid hoppid
```

The Process Selection option `p` selects the process(es) for which information is to be shown, in this case `$pid`.
The Output Modifier `h` suppresses printing of column header, e. g. `PPID`.
The Output Format Control option `o` is used to choose the information supplied by `ps`, in this case just `ppid`, the parent process ID.

```
ps p`…` hocomm
```

The previous command's output (which is the parent process ID) replaces the backquoted command, so that we get a `ps` command quite similar to the one described above, this time with the parent selected and its command name chosen for output by `comm`.

See [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) and [ps - report process status](http://www.manpages.info/linux/ps.1.html).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the command you provided? PS: I am not very good at scripting. Thanks!

Comment: @Gautam Singh: I've added details.